# Kona Dr dew - drop handlebars

Tags: hybrid-bike

So I have a kona Dr dew which is technically a hybrid. More road bike than mountain. I've only had this bike less than a year but I really like the look of it but I want to install drop handlebars. I understand this will also mean I will need to change the brakes and shifters. Anyone know a good reasonably priced set up I could use?

Here's the spec of the bike

FRAME MATERIAL  Kona 6061 Aluminum Butted
SIZES   46, 49, 53, 56, 59, 61cm
REAR SHOCK  n/a
FORK    Kona Project Two Aluminum
CRANKARMS   SRAM Via Centro
CHAINRINGS  32/48t
B/B SRAM Powerspline
PEDALS  VP 198
CHAIN   SRAM PC1031
FREEWHEEL   SRAM PG1030 11-36t 10 spd
CHAINGUIDE  n/a
F/D SRAM Via Centro
R/D SRAM Via Centro
SHIFTERS    SRAM Via Centro
BRAKE CALIPERS  Shimano M446 Hydraulic
FRONT BRAKE ROTOR   Shimano 160mm
REAR BRAKE ROTOR    Shimano 160mm
BRAKE LEVERS    Shimano M446 Hydraulic
HEADSET TH ZST No.10
HANDLEBAR   Kona Deluxe Energy
STEM    Kona Commuter
SEATPOST    Kona Double Clamp w/offset
SEAT CLAMP  Kona Clamp
GRIPS   Velo Ergo
SADDLE  Freedom Aon
FRONT HUB   Formula
REAR HUB    Shimano M475
SPOKES  Sandvik Stainless 15g fr / 14g rr
RIMS    Freedom Ryder 21
FRONT TIRE  Continental CityRide 700x32c
REAR TIRE   Continental CityRide 700x32c

Comment: This is likely off topic since it is a request for a product recommendation.  Unless you are planning to do the work yourself, you may want to investigate what your LBS would recommend.  Kona used to make a bike exactly like what you are seeking called the Dew Drop, but they haven't done it for a few years apparently.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drop Bar for Lespo Frame?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/21551/drop-bar-for-lespo-frame)

Answer (score 2):

About two years ago I converted my 2011 Dew to drop bars. I opted for Avid BB7 
Road mechanical disc brakes as they are compatible with short pull road brake levers. For shifters I chose to use bar ends because of their lower price and more simple design compared to STI levers.

I ended up with a cost of about $325 for my 8 speed bar end shifters, Cane Creek short pull road levers, Avid BB7 Disc brakes, Salsa Cowbell 3 handlebars, and bar tape. I would expect to pay that much for the shifters alone if you opt for STI shifters as opposed to bar ends (the economical choice).