# Converting Specialized Sirrus hybrid to drop bars

Tags: hybrid-bike

I have a Specialized Sirrus 2014 equipped w/ disc brakes. I'm quite happy with it for my commutes, yet after after spending a year with it, I kinda still long for the drop bars.

What components would need to be throw out and replaced in order to give my Sirrus drop bars? Does it generally seem like a good idea to rebuild a hybrid in this way?

(What I like about Sirrus are disc brakes, tire size, fenders and rack -- all very practical for commuting and reason for me not to get a proper road bike.)

Comment: Which Sirrus model is this? The answer depends on whether it has mechanical or hydraulic disks, though both are going to end up expensive and lot of work. I would suggest selling the bike and getting a cyclocross or touring one.

Comment: Similar to this topic: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/31752/kona-dr-dew-drop-handlebars/31754#31754

Comment: you need a drop bars and a pair of shifters. However, this may change the geometry of the bike since a hybrid has a longer top tube than one on a road bike.

Comment: did you ever get anywhere with this. I'm also keen to do this.

Comment: I get you don't have the rep for a comment but this is not a valid question.  I am really surprised this has not received an answer.  Or least a duplicate.